# Google Maps Marker Update

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have been working on a Google Maps system, currently I am able to obtain my current location, the only issue I am having at the moment is that I do **not** know how to update my current location everytime I want to use the application outside.

@push('scripts')

```
        // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
        // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
        // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
        // locate you.
        var map, infoWindow;
        function initMap() {
            let spain = {lat:40.417953, lng: -3.714312};
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: spain,
                zoom: 15
            });

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            let markers = {!! $markers->toJson() !!};

            let hotspotLoc = {
                lat: markers[0].lat,
                lng: markers[0].lng
            };
            map.setCenter(hotspotLoc);

            // Loading in Markers from the database
            $.each(markers, function (key, marker) {
                let id = marker.id;
                let name = marker.name;
                let addres = marker.addres;
                let lesson = 0;
                if (marker.lesson && marker.lesson.length > 0) {
                    lesson = marker.lesson[0].id;
                }

                let lat = marker.lat;
                let lng = marker.lng;
                let type = marker.type;

                let markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));

                let mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: markerLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    lesson: lesson
                });

                // Trigger marker when moving near to it
                new google.maps.event.trigger(markers, 'click');

                mark.setMap(map);
            });
            // Try HTML5 geolocation.
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                    infoWindow.setContent('Current location');
                    infoWindow.open(map);
                    map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function() {
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }

        }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{env('G_MAPS_API')}}&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```

Here is my script, hopefully someone knows how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Depends on how and when you want to retrieve your location. You want it to update every few minute give it an interval, you want it to refresh whenever the user wants it, add a button. you got your getCurrentPosition function so you can use it, or am I getting the question wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

I would suggest trying `watchPosition()` ([Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) & [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)) instead of `getCurrentPosition()`.

So you would change:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {});
```

To something like:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
   var pos = {
     lat: position.coords.latitude,
     lng: position.coords.longitude
   };
   map.setCenter(pos);
});
```